# Cambiar comportamiento de editor: Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Mi pregunta se refiere al **comportamiento del *árbol de directorios* o *explorador de directorios* en cuanto al plegado**.

En *sublime text* o *atom*, cuando pliegas un directorio todos los subdirectorios mantienen su estado, es decir, si lo vuelves a desplegar están como estaban antes.
VSC por el contrario pliega todos los subdirectorios cuando pliegas un directorio. Al abrirlo, tienes que abrir de nuevo todo el árbol cuando necesitas acceder a un fichero...

¿hay alguna forma de cambiar este comportamiento?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede "mejorar" al **modificar la configuración**:

1. Abrir la configuración del editor.
2. Buscar "explorer".
3. Desmarcar la opción: `Explorer:Compact Folders`

**La opción Compact Folders** del *Explorador* muestra los directorios plegados por defecto si no tienen contenido, p.e.:

```
src/
  |-- index.xd
  |-- services/printer/
                 |-- printer.xd
```

*Los directorios que sólo contienen un directorio no se muestran escalonadamente.*

**La opción "Auto Reveal"**, también del *Explorer*, mueve el menú cuando seleccionamos un fichero abierto, para centrarlo en el mismo, puede no ser lo mejor si estamos trabajando con varios ficheros en diferentes directorios, poner a `false`.